# How to get this output to round to 2 decimal places?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I cannot for the life of me get this number to output as XX.XX, it always has around 10 decimal places e.g. XX.XXXXXXX. I have researched and tried everything I can think of but nothing seems to work, please help :)

```
,CAST(AVG(case when Is_Open = 0 then CAST(Reported_Duration as bigint) end) as decimal(10,2)) / 3600.00 as 'Average Reported Closure Time (hours)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `cast` the result as `varchar` to see the `0`s.

```
cast(yourresult as varchar)
```

Use `round` to get the result truncated to 2 places after the decimal.

```
round(youresult, 2)

ROUND(AVG(case when Is_Open = 0 
          then CAST(Reported_Duration as bigint) end) / 3600.00 , 2)
```

Comment: huh? I'm not sure I get what you're saying, I just want to result set to output as 00.00 instead of 00.000000 (the zero's would be various numbers though)

Comment: i thought you only had a problem with integers, showing up as integers. Hence the previous answer.

Comment: My problem is rounding the number to 2 decimal places

Comment: that is what `round` does.i included your expression too. it would help if you show some sample data too

Comment: What the heck, I tried round so many times, but for some reason this time it worked! I must've been placing it in the wrong part of the query or something?

Comment: yes, you would have included it before the final evaluation of the expression.